# Kafka or Database which one should come first in streaming data pipeline?

Tags: database, apache-kafka

I read some where that "Streaming into a DB to then stream out of the DB is not a perfect choice, if you have the option." he says it would be best to stream from the sensor into Kafka, and then from there Kafka into MySQL, Mongo, webapp, etc. I think it may apply for website data streams as well.

Is there any advantages in using this architecture?

Comment: There aren't many client side Javascript libraries for producing into Kafka... The backend can use Kafka or a database... What exactly are you trying to ask? Kafka doesn't persist data forever by default, and is not queryable like any database you connect it to... Maybe Mongo makes sense for some data, but Mysql or Cassandra or Hadoop is better for other data, so **it depends**, but Kafka can independently send to each

Comment: Typically I'd suggest getting the data into kafka close to the source system if you can. This has the advantage of letting all of the potential sinks get at the data right away. If you're talking weblogs and click stream data, go to Kafka first. You can probably find a connector that does what you want. Then let everything else subscribe and you can do any stream processing you want as well before it hits the database.

Comment: I want to stream click data from web site(such as wikipedia) to kafka then to storm  for processing. 1. Web data-->DB -->kafka -->Storm --> or 2. Web data --> connector --> Kafka -->storm --> I am trying to implement 1 but some sources say 2 is better. I wanted to know the advantage of 2. @dawsaw gave a very good explanation.

Comment: I'm not sure what the "extra" steps of pushing the data into a db and then retrieving them from the db to push them to Kafka will give you as a benefit? Unless you already have a pipe for that kind of data into something like InfluxDB or similar, then going via a db seems like an indirection.
I agree with dawsaw on keeping Kafka close to the source.

Comment: This is my first streaming system. most of the tools are new to me too. So my first conception was push data through DB but now my research and views here give me an alternative. In fact i want a good system and to use good practice to integrate the big data tools for efficiency. and it's recommended i maintain a push-model throughout the pipe.